# How to modify pageSize at ProductListComponentService

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

Actually I created a new ProductListComponent and a new ProductListComponentService, they have the same code as the original, I only changed the value **protected defaultPageSize** at ProductListComponentService but it doesn't have effect.

Any Ideas?

**My Product List Component**

```
export class CustomProductListComponent {
  model$: Observable<ProductSearchPage> = this.productListComponentService
    .model$;

   constructor(private pageLayoutService: PageLayoutService, private productListComponentService: ProductListComponentService, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private scrollConfig?: ViewConfig) {
    }
}
```

Original Source Code: https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront/components/ProductListComponent.html#source

**My Product List Component Service**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ProductListComponentService {
  protected defaultPageSize = 12;
```

Original Source Code: https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront/injectables/ProductListComponentService.html#source

Comment: Please elaborate your question with more details and possibly some code.

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: Done, I added more code.

Answer (score 0):

Just for more clarification, you created a `CustomProductListComponent` and a `CustomProductListComponentService`, which has the same source code as the original one correct? If yes, it should work ootb, when as you mentioned, modified the value of defaultPageSize to 12.

Only thing I can think of is how you might of configured Spartacus for your needs by having things on the queryParams. If so, you can look at the function `getCriteriaFromRoute` in `ProductListComponentService`, which says to use the value for the queryParams if it exists, or the default value if not.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, you can ask your questions using comment's section, then you can improve your answer before posting it.